# getChildHtml('content')

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, frontend

I am using Magento 1.7.

In `1column.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/template/page`, which is the page template I'm using, I find the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

which is responsible for adding the content to my page.

However, I would like to add some more content to my page, so that it is displayed when this line of code is executed. But I don't know how I should proceed. I read about the layout and blocks system, but still I am not able to add some content to my page.

I know that I can add content to `header.phtml` or `footer.phtml` under `design/frontend/default/custom_theme/template/page` which is then displayed in the frontend. However, in the case of what is inserted by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`, I don't know how to proceed. Could anyone explain me which steps I need to follow in order to add some additional content?

I am pretty new to Magento, so if you think there is some lack of info in my question, please tell me and I will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to add some content via a simple template file you can add the following in your theme `app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/layout/local.xml`

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom.content" template="my/custom/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then you just need to create your `app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/template/my/custom/template.phtml` file with the content you need inside it

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Now I just added my content, is there any way to control in which position it will appear? Is it just a matter of CSS, or is there another way of arranging blocks using the layout system?

Comment: @LeCodeur yes you can use `before` and `after` attributes in your `<block>` declaration. The value of those attributes is another block name (defined in the xml layout files). This way you can manage the position

Answer (score 1):

Just for your knowledge go to `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml`

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>
```

`content` is a block name defined over there inside

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml"> </block>
```

These are structural blocks defined inside `page.xml` which defines how a page structure should be.

**Now if you notice the block type of `content` block you will see `core/text_list`. In Magento if a block is `core/text_list` type then it will call any block inside it automatically.**

**So as per @Raphael's example**

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom.content" template="my/custom/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

You just need to create the `template.phtml` file in `my/custom/` location. And it will be called automatically.

In other cases(in case of other block types) you need to call that block by using `getChildHtml('alias name or name');`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that clarifies it for me. Now I just added my content, is there any way to control in which position it will appear? Is it just a matter of CSS, or is there another way of arranging blocks using the layout system?

Comment: @LeCodeur do as Raphael is saying.